# What is wrong with my query? From - To date

Tags: php, mysql

On the other reports it works fine but when I did a join query somehow the from , to date does not work , it shows nothing.

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales_detail LEFT JOIN product ON product.productid=sales_detail.productid LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.salesid=sales_detail.salesid LEFT JOIN customer ON sales.userid=customer.userid WHERE product.supplierid='".$_SESSION['id'] ."'BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ORDER BY sales.sales_date desc");
$stmt1->execute();
```

Comment: where are you using to date?. did you tried `var_dump`ing the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using multiple where clause, you need `and` or `or` operator. 
BTW please read through [SQL INJECTIONS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

```
  $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("select * from sales_detail left join product on product.productid=sales_detail.productid left join sales on sales.salesid=sales_detail.salesid left join customer on sales.userid=customer.userid where product.supplierid='".$_SESSION['id'] ."' AND BETWEEN YOURFIELD_HERE '$from' AND '$to' order by sales.sales_date desc");
  $stmt1->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing date field in Where condition?

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("select * from sales_detail left join product on product.productid=sales_detail.productid left join sales on sales.salesid=sales_detail.salesid left join customer on sales.userid=customer.userid where product.supplierid='".$_SESSION['id'] ."' AND TABLE.DATEFIELD BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' order by sales.sales_date desc");
$stmt1->execute();
```

Comment: @Rav great Kudos :)